# How do you make Django databases that auto generate their own name?

Tags: django

How do I make Django databases that don't know their names yet.

For an example if I have a new user called 'fred' and I want Django to automatically make a data base called 'fred_questions' for him. How do I do it?

Then for another user who signs up, say 'jane' then Django will make a 'jane_questions' data base for her too.

If you could direct me to the the right places to learn this it would be great.

Comment: Why would you not use an indexed column in a normal table instead?

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your purpose buddy but if you need to do it You can check out this link.

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=2770040

If it still not helpfull.Kindly comment.  cheers :-)